# How to make a record completely readonly based on a condition in odoo

Tags: xml, odoo-8

Instead of having a readonly attribute for every fields (since I am using a readonly attribute already for every fields based on some other conditions), is there any other method is there to make an entire record readonly based on a condition.

I am already using readonly attribute in fields,

```
<field name="name" attrs="{'readonly':['|',('state','=','aban'),'&amp;',('close_ticket','=',True),('edit','=',False)]}"/>
```

Comment: in python you can do in case "if you have common condition for all fields", create method and call it from the fields in the .py

Comment: @PrakashSharma Can you please give an example